# Deleting repeated information in a column based in a value of another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have these two dataframes:

Dt1

```
barcode ID
1       AA
2       AA
3       AA
4       BB
5       BB
6       CC
7       DD
8       EE
```

Dt 2

```
barcode weight
1       55
3       45
6       35
7       80
```

I would like to merge the dataframes in a way where the IDs, repeated or not, will deleted based on the barcodes, my final dataframe will be like this:

```
   barcode  ID 
    4       BB   
    5       BB
    8       EE
```

I tried several commands, but any one worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using

```
Idremove = Dt1$ID[Dt1$barcode %in% Dt2$barcode]
Dt1 = Dt1[!Dt1$ID %in% Idremove, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

Dt1%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  filter(all(!barcode %in% Dt2$barcode))%>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  barcode ID   
    <int> <chr>
1       4 BB   
2       5 BB   
3       8 EE
```

Data:

```
Dt1 <- tribble(
  ~barcode, ~ID,
     1L,       'AA',
     2L,       'AA',
     3L,       'AA',
     4L,       'BB',
     5L,       'BB',
     6L,       'CC',
     7L,       'DD',
     8L,       'EE')

Dt2 <- tribble (
  ~barcode, ~weight,
    1L,       55L,
    3L,       45L,
    6L,       35L,
    7L,       80L)
```